# Projectile motion equations @ very (!) high starting velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, projectile

I've already searched Physics StackExchange for some similar question but I didn't find anything about this.

Assumptions:

- Earth is a perfect sphere with it's core (X,Y,Z) -> (0,0,0) as a reference-frame center
- Air resistance can be ignored
- Earth rotation can be ignored
- Moon gravity-effect can be ignored

And if I know (projectile starting properties):

- Current Earth GPS-coordinates
- Starting angle
- Starting direction (relative to (0,0,0))
- Starting velocity (can be larger than Earth-escaping speed)
- (mass of the projectile is irrelevant (I guess) when we know starting velocity of the projectile)

How could I calculate aprox. coordinates of a projectile landing somewhere around the Earth globe (OR detect that projectile will "leave" the Earth)?

EDIT: I've found tons of links on the net about projectile trajectories when starting velocities are quite small (& Earth can be considered like a flat plane), but non about upper situation.

Comment: You can do it with Keplar's laws. The formulas do not come out particularly simple.

Comment: As Steve says: compute the orbit and find the intersections with the surface. But neglecting air resistance is *silly* for cases where the projectile lands far around the globe (because small changes in the speed and course when leaving the atmosphere will make a big difference in range.) and even sillier for projectiles very near escape speed (because small changes can switch which behavior is exhibited).

Comment: Thx both of you for your comments! I know air resistance has a huge influence on a trajectory, but in my (specific) case (-> computer game) it can be neglected. Anyways, thx again! :-)

Comment: @sabiland: if you're doing a computer game, then you are just timestepping the projectile, right?  You know that it's coming down because you do the simulation, and you see it coming down.

Comment: Might [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/782/how-to-calculate-a-ballistic-trajectory-for-a-suborbital-flight) be what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, thx David Z :)